# How do we bind gridview with list of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview

A quick question.. I am trying to create list of objects and assign it to a gridview. But it seems to have no data?

Also, I would like to save user input every time the user click add button (Just need an idea). What would be my best approach for that?

```
List<OrderItems> orderItem = new List<OrderItems>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    orderItem.Add(new OrderItems("Test1", "Test2"));
    orderItem.Add(new OrderItems("Test1", "Test2"));
    orderItem.Add(new OrderItems("Test1", "Test2"));
    orderItem.Add(new OrderItems("Test1", "Test2"));
    orderItem.Add(new OrderItems("Test1", "Test2"));
}
protected void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Producing an error of no data
    grdTest.DataSource = orderItem;
    grdTest.DataBind();

}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class OrderItems
{
    private string prodId;
    private string qty;

    public OrderItems()
    {

    }

    public OrderItems(string prodId, string quantity)
    {
        this.prodId = prodId;
        this.qty = quantity;
    }

    public string productId
    {
        get
        {
            return productId;
        }
    }

    public string quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OrderItems` class is wrong. Included correct one in comments

```
public string productId
{
    get
    {
        return productId; //Change it to return prodId;
    }
}

public string quantity
{
    get
    {
        return quantity; //Change it to return qty;
    }
}
```

This is currently going into infinite loop.

Otherwise, I don't see any issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect your code fragment to be working and need help locating the problem, or are you asking how to code data binding and data aggregation in xaml/c# code?

Your code is not complete and will not work. You need to perform an add operation to the list on button click which you can pull the input from text boxes. If you need the list data to reflect on to your xaml/display, you need to add notifier to trigger the UI to refresh on data change.

You can learn how to do two way data binding properly from the [Data-Binding sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5).

Comment: No, currently forget about the saving inputs. the code above is just for test purpose and the values are hard coded. I just wanted to know if I can bind a list of objects like I made above with a gridview? Why does it say my list doesn't contain any data?

Comment: I noticed you didn't call Page_Load(), which add your hard coded data. Did you missed that or didn't include the code such as this.Loaded += Page_Load; in the page constructor?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the best pattern to use. I would create a static repository class. Why create items in page load since you are not binding on page_load. Just create the items in the button click but I would use a repository class since you are creating an entity anyways. Why write more code than you have to, your class is wrong, just use the shorthand method. Here's a good design pattern to learn.

I would use an integer for Quantity btw.

```
public class OrderItem
{

   public string ProductId { get; set; }    
   public int Quantity { get; set; }

}


public static class OrderItemRepository()
{
    public static List<OrderItem> GetOrderItems()
    {
        List<OrderItem> rv = new List<OrderItem>();
        rv.Add(new OrderItem{ ProductId="1", Quantity=2});

        return rv;

    }

}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         //bind grid here if need be.
     }
}

private BindGrid()
{ 

    grdTest.DataSource = OrderItemRepository.GetOrderItems();
    grdTest.DataBind();

 }


protected void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     BindGrid();

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The above code was just a test of storing values. In fact, currently I created a class to hold all my values within a list. So I take in the user input, pass the values on button_click to a class function that creates an object in the list. So as for delete and update. Thanks :)